# Why are statsmodels and sklearn returning different Lasso estimates?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels, bayesian, lasso-regression

I'm currently doing a project investigating the Bayesian Lasso and part of the project involves running some simulations. It can be shown that if we set independent and identically distributed conditional Laplace priors on the regression coefficients beta, the posterior mode is a frequentist Lasso estimate with tuning parameter 2 x sigma x lambda. So to check my work, I often make use of both SciKit and Statmodels (in particular their Lasso implementations) to calculate the frequentist Lasso estimate that should be approximately equal to the posterior mode (using the medians of sigma and lambda as estimates for 2 x sig x lam) and superimpose them onto my histograms. In the simulations I've run involving independent predictor variables, all Lasso estimates that I compute with scikit and statsmodels align, and they appear to coincide with the posterior mode when I superimpose them on my histograms.

However, if I use virtually the same code but in the case of (a) multicollinearity, (b) p > n or (c) n > p but n small e.g. n=12 and p = 9, sklearn and statsmodels output different Lasso estimates occasionally for the same tuning hyperparameter, which is confusing. Here's my code for the multicollinear predictors case (lam=1 here):

```
sigmamedian = np.median(np.sqrt(burned_sig2_tracesLam))
# Check with SciKit's Lasso 
skmodel = Lasso(alpha=2*sigmamedian*lam/(2*len(y_train)),fit_intercept=False,tol=1e-12)
skmodel = skmodel.fit(X_trainStd,y_train-np.mean(y_train))
print(skmodel.coef_)

# StatsModel's Lasso
smLasso = sm.OLS(y_train - np.mean(y_train),X_trainStd).fit_regularized(alpha=2*sigmamedian*lam/(2*len(y_train)))
print(smLasso.params)
```

The output in this case is:
[ 0.28284396, -1.23878332, 1.08344865, 0.29263474, 0. , 0.00655085]
[ 0.45950192, -1.32361768, 0.8906759, 0.28951489, 0. , 0.]

These aren't the same, which is confusing because I've checked the documentation and I haven't made the common mistake of dealing with the intercept parameters the same way in scikit and statsmodels, the tuning hyperparameters inputted are the same, both modules use coordinate descent and LASSO estimates should be unique for n < p (and actually Tibshirani has shown that LASSO estimates are almost surely unique if the data is generated from a continuous distribution, even if p > n). After superimposing both of these onto the histograms of the posterior distributions, it appears to be that scikit's implementation that returns the posterior mode (or at least, a very good approximation of it). If I change lambda to 2, then scikit and statsmodels still return different things but statsmodels returns the estimate that accurately approximates the posterior mode.

I also generated data with p=25 and n = 20; the theory suggests that Lasso should set 5 of the coefficients to zero, but neither scikit nor statsmodels did this.

What's going on here?

Comment: What is the numerical value of alpha that you end up using here?  With some dummy data, I start to get disagreement between statsmodels and sklearn when alpha is smallish.  (A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make it easer for someone to help you.)

Comment: (I'm not a lasso expert). How large is your correlation?  I don't think that "estimates are almost surely unique" rules out local minima in small samples. With perfect correlation, there will not be a unique solution. If there are local minima, then it depends on the algorithm to which the solution converges.